# Dynamic "Columns:=Array(1,2,3)" in RemoveDuplicates function excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic-arrays

I am new to VBA.
Currently I am trying to remove duplicate rows from a non-header spreadsheet where,
`lastColumn` is last column of worksheet.
`lastRow` is last row of worksheet.

It is working fine for:

```
ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1,1), Cells (lastRow,lastColumn)). RemoveDuplicates(Columns:=Array(1,2,3), Headers:=xlNo)
```

- But it will work only for 3 columns each time.

I want to remove duplicate rows from Excel worksheet by making Array dynamically. Trying the same using `Application.Evaluate` function to create a sequence of Array from first to last column of spreadsheet.

```
myArray=Evaluate ("Row(1:" & lastColumn & ")")
ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1,1), Cells (lastRow,lastColumn)). RemoveDuplicates(Columns:=myArray, Headers:=xlNo)
```

But getting

> "invalid procedure call or argument" error.

Is there any possible way to do it for a header/ non-header spreadsheet?

Comment: Dim x as Variant 
x = Evaluate (Columns("A":"Z"))
ReDim Preserve x(0 To lcol-1) As Variant
.Range(Cells(1,1),Cells(lrow,lcol)). RemoveDuplicates (x), xlNo

Comment: The above way solved the problem.